# How should I update my database after adding a migration using dotnet ef commands

Tags: .net, sql-server

I've been trying to update my database in Visual Studio, but when I run `dotnet ef database update`, I get this error over and over again:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase

I've tried several things but nothing worked yet.

Comment: Have you googled that error message? There are quite a few questions scattered all over the internet solving this issue. Also, you said you tried several things. What are they?